# Is finding a subset with exact cut with other given subsets NP-hard?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, combinatorics, computation-theory

I am trying to figure out whether the following problem is NP-hard:

```
Given  G_1,..,G_n subsets of {1..m}
       c_1,..,c_n non-negative integers in {0..m}
Find   T subset of {1..m}
S.T.   for all i=1..n, T intersects G_i in exactly c_i elements
```

I tried to find reductions to NP problems such as *coloring*, or P problems such as *matching*, but on both cases could think of exponential conversion algorithm (i.e. one that takes into account all subsets of *G_i* of size *c_i*), which doesn't help me much :(

A side note: would any restrictions on the parameters make this problem much easier?
For instance, would *m<< n* make a computational difference (we would still be looking for an algorithm that is polynomial in *m*)?
What if we knew that some of the constants *c_i* were zero?

Would appreciate any insight :)

Comment: I think you are asking if it is in NP-Hard, not NP. NP is any algorithm that can be solved polynomially on non deterministic turing machine (or alternative definition, given a solution, you can efficiently check of the solution is correct).

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NP-Complete problem, and is a generalization of [Hitting Set Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Exact_hitting_set). Proof of NP-Completeness follows.

The problem is in NP (trivial - given a solution `T`, it is easy to check the intersection with each of Gi, and verify if its size is Ci).

It is also NP-Complete, assuming you are looking for *minimal* such `T`, with reduction from [Exact Hitting Set Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Exact_hitting_set):

Where the decision problem of exact hitting set is:

> Given a universe of elements `U`, subsets `S1,...,Sk`, and a number
>   `m` - is there a subset `S` of `U` of size at most `m` that contains
>   exactly one element from each `Si`?

Given instance of hitting-set problem `(S1,S2,...Sk,d)` - reduce it to this problem with `Gi=Si, ci = 1`, if the minimal solution of this problem is of size `d`, there is also a solution to exact hitting set of size `d` (and vise versa).